# What is the condition to check if we are in admin or frontend?

Tags: conditional-tags

What is the condition to check if we are in admin or frontend?

I want to add_action not in backend, but only in frontend.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look at the [`is_admin()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) [conditional tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags):

```
function wpse106895_dummy_func() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        // do your thing
    }
}
add_action( 'some-hook', 'wpse106895_dummy_func' );
```

[`is_admin()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) returns true, if the URL being accessed is in the dashboard / wp-admin. Hence it's negation (via the [not operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)) is true when in the frontend.

**Update**, see comments below:

```
function wpse106895_dummy_func() {
    // do your thing
}
if ( ! is_admin() ) add_action( 'some-hook', 'wpse106895_dummy_func' );
```

will save you overhead.

Comment: `if ( is_admin() ) add_action()`. Do not populate the filter array with values you never need.

Comment: I often check(ed) inside the callback - after all, I figured, the statement(s) will never be interpreted, if the condition isn't met. The overhead in the filter array I did not consider. Ever.

Comment: `! is_admin()` reports true though on `wp-admin` and `wp-login.php`, so it's not a check for frontend

Comment: Keep in mind that `is_admin` won't check the cron and ajax calls. So if you really need frontend only this might not be sufficient.

Comment: To followup as @janw mentioned, a true frontend check would look like this `( ! is_admin() || wp_doing_ajax() ) && ! wp_doing_cron()`

Comment: @WPExplorer - what is the opposite of your 'true frontend check' - checking for the 'back end', and not editing a comment there, or adding a comment reply on the admin/comments screen?

Answer (score 2):

Backend and frontend on modern web is more of a state of mind than actual distinct url pattern, or code. Whether a specific page fulls into being a backend or frontend might change based on the kind of user is accessing the page.

In the context of wordpress the question might be rephrased to "I want to add action when the theme is generating HTML" (which, might or not cover all front end generation in your specific case), and for this, the best hook to use is `template_redirect` which is fired just before wordpress goes into deciding which template of the theme to use to generate the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `is_admin()` function not work properly if you need to check in `Widget::widget()` is the code retrived on front-end or on admin page.

Because of that there is a problem to distinguish the view of what the widget displays on the blog and what on the `widget.php` subpage of the admin panel. On dashboard `widgets.php` page, widget preview is an output from `<iframe>` HTML tag, so `is_admin()` is not a good solution in such case.

Because there is no `is_front_end()` function in Wordpress, the interesting solution is to create a function which check is `get_header()` and `get_footer()` functions has been fired during the current request. Simple function.

```
<?php 

    function is_front_end() {
        if ( did_action( 'get_header' ) || did_action( 'get_footer' ) ) 
            return true;
    }

?>
```

**Inspiration thanks to [@TheDeadMedic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1685/thedeadmedic) answer:**

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/228236/84343