# Check if partial file is called from within header.php or footer.php

Tags: get-template-part

I am including a partial file both in `header.php` and in `footer.php` with `get_template_part('content-form');`

Is there an `if` clause I can use to check from where the file is being called? If it is called from within `footer.php`, then I would like to add a class name.

```
<div class="default-class <?php if (called_from_footer) echo 'footer-class'; ?>">
</div>
```

I could do this and style accordingly if there isn't a better solution, I am just curious:

```
<div class=footer-container">
    <?php get_template_part('content-form') ;?>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, it's the eternal "can i please pass a parameter with `get_template_part`" question. Lookee here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176804/passing-a-variable-to-get-template-part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a *true* solution to your problem (checking which template loaded another), but it will work to test if the footer has been loaded or not, and thus if it's loading your partial:

```
if ( did_action( 'get_footer' ) ) echo 'footer-class';
```

Comment: Might not be perfect but under such circumstances I probably would just do it and not bother with anything elaborate. :D

Answer (score 2):

There are many good solutions for doing this, you should follow the link that cjbj has provided in the comments.

I am suggesting to use PHP's [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function:

```
function wpse_228223_verify_caller_file( $file_name, $files = array(), $dir = '' ) {

    if( empty( $files ) ) {
        $files = debug_backtrace();
    }

    if( ! $dir ) {
        $dir = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/';
    }

    $dir = str_replace( "/", "\\", $dir );
    $caller_theme_file = array();

    foreach( $files as $file ) {
        if( false !== mb_strpos($file['file'], $dir) ) {
            $caller_theme_file[] = $file['file'];
        }
    }

    if( $file_name ) {
        return in_array( $dir . $file_name, $caller_theme_file );
    }

    return;

}
```

Usage:

In your `content-form` template, pass the file name in the first param:

```
echo var_dump( wpse_228223_verify_caller_file( 'header.php' ) ); // called from header
echo var_dump( wpse_228223_verify_caller_file( 'footer.php' ) ); // called from footer
```

and there in your template you can add the appropriate class names..

Please give it few tests first. The way I tested it it worked fine. Since you are creating your own custom template which won't be called by default unless your call it, it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I think that best solution for your specific issue is [the one form **@TheDeadMedic**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/228236/35541).

It might be a little "fragile" because `do_action('get_footer')` can be done in any file... but what's not fragile in WordPress?

An alternative solution, just for "academic purpose" could be make use of PHP [`get_included_files()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) checking that `footer.php` was required:

```
function themeFileRequired($file) {

    $paths = array(
        wp_normalize_path(get_stylesheet_directory().'/'.$file.'.php'),
        wp_normalize_path(get_template_directory().'/'.$file.'.php'),
    );

    $included = array_map('wp_normalize_path', get_included_files());

    $intersect = array_intersect($paths, $included);

    return ! empty($intersect);
}
```

And then:

```
<div class="default-class <?= if (themeFileRequired('footer') echo 'footer-class'; ?>">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want it quick 'n dirty, just use a global variable (hey, WP is doing it all the time, so why can't you?). Set it before the call and read it afterwards. Like this:

In `functions.php`: `global $contentform_origin = '';`

In `header.php`: `$contentform_origin = 'header'; get_template_part('content-form');`

In `footer.php`: `$contentform_origin = 'footer'; get_template_part('content-form');`

In `content-form.php`: `<div class="default-class <?php echo $contentform_origin ?>-class">
</div>`

Don't forget to declare `$contentform_origin` at the beginning op each php file.