# Best way of making multiple sidebars

Tags: sidebar

I am very well aware of `how to make multiple sidebars`. But I believe my way is not proper way of adding multiple sidebars.

**This is how I add multiple sidebars**

If I simply wants to create a sidebar then I use sidebar.php file. BUT if I want to use another sidebar then I have to create another php file
like `sidebar-new.php`. Then call this file as

```
 <?php 
      get_sidebar('new'); 
 ?>
```

That mean if I want to create 4 sidebar then I have to make 4 php files!

BUT I have seen many themes (In wordpress market) that provide many sidebars but they contains only one php file for sidebar (sidebar.php)!
How do they do that? I have learned about making sidebars from google earlier but in search I only get the results that I am using right now (create multiple files for multiple sidebars).

So how can I create multiple sidebar without making Multiple php files!!???

Comment: I would look at creating a sidebar OOP class and then rather call the class instead of `get_sidebar`. This way, you can pass different values to the class as needed. I cannot really see any other solution without getting really messy

Answer (score 8):

Defining new sidebar with in your functions.php

```
<?php

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {

   register_sidebar(array(
   'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
   'after_widget' => '</li>',
   'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
   'after_title' => '</h2>'
   ));

}?>
```

Once these are functions are defined, you will notice the extra sidebar appear in the WordPress Dashboard under the Appearance > Widgets option. It’s here that you can drag and drop all your widgets into your various sidebars.

```
<?php

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {

   register_sidebar(array(
   'name' => 'sidebar 1',
   'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
   'after_widget' => '</div>',
   'before_title' => '<h2>',
   'after_title' => '</h2>'
    ));

   register_sidebar(array(
   'name' => 'footer sidebar 1',
   'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
   'after_widget' => '</div>',
   'before_title' => '<h2>',
   'after_title' => '</h2>'
   ));

}?>
```

Adding new sidebar to your template

Within your sidebar.php file, change the call to your existing sidebar to include its name that you defined within the functions.php file earlier.

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar 1') ) : ?>

   <h2>Articles by month</h2>
   <ul>
      <?php wp_get_archives('title_li=&type=monthly'); ?>
   </ul>
   <h2>Categories</h2>
   <ul>
      <?php wp_list_categories('show_count=0&title_li='); ?>
   </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

To add your new sidebar, you can either copy the above code or you can simply copy the following lines. Add these lines to wherever you’d like your new widgets to appear. In this example you can see from the name that I’m placing mine in the footer of my website. As before, don’t forget to specify the correct sidebar name. In the above code, the html that appears between the php statements is what will appear when there are no widgets added to your sidebar. This ‘default’ code can obviously be modified to suit your theme. In the following code, since there is no extra html, nothing will be displayed unless a widget has been added into the sidebar within your WordPress dashboard.

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('footer sidebar 1') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: ok I m little confused here! First, why u didnt use id in registering the sidebar And how do I call sidebar in my homepage? like this `get_sidebar();`!

Comment: ID is not use because calling sidebar through widget area and you can call   on home page by simple calling name of widget area at your homepage.

Comment: But why I cant see any sidebar (that just registered) in apearance -> widget ?

Comment: Did you apply above code? There is multiple way to add sidebar in your theme file.

Comment: First code I did write in functions.php and second code I typed in functions.php (and later in home.php as well) and the last code I typed in sidebar.php. What else I need to do and where?

Comment: so what response do you get at your admin area?

Comment: That code makes no effect in admin area! Have u tested this method?

Comment: One more thing! when I put Id in registered sidebar function then it started to appear in  apearance -> widget

Comment: you have to create sidebar and put sidebar name in function and than calling it through widget area. Yes i have made this code and used in my project.

Comment: register side bar in widget and calling it through widget area at your homepage clear?

Comment: shud I call it like get_sidebar(); or in diff way. If any diff way of calling it then show me

Comment: calling like this  and check the result <div class="third">
    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar('your sidebar name')) : ?>
    <h2>You sidebar name</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
   </div>

Comment: No no no! it seems u r getting all wrong..  Are u suggesting me to call with this function `get_sidebar();`. If yes, then it will call both sidebar at the same time. What if I wanted to show one widget in footer and other widget in header. This case is not seems possible with ur code  and that was the actual question of mine!

Answer (score 3):

You can differentiate between sidebars **inside** `sidebar.php`. I don't know what your purpose is, but let's suppose you want different sidebars on single posts/pages and other pages.

In your `functions.php` you would register two sidebars with id's `singular` and `default` in the usual way with [`register_sidebar`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar).

Then in `sidebar.php` you would include something like

```
if (is_singular) {dynamic_sidebar('singular');}
else {dynamic_sidebar('default');}
```

Of course, there are many ways to vary on this. You can display different sidebars depending on category or maybe no sidebar at all on a special page template called 'one-column'.

Comment: I have tried ur solution and result comes out as per my expectations. It only showing 1 sidebar! What I actually wanted to know a way of adding multiple sidebars on one page and in that page on the location of my choice.

Comment: You mean you want multiple calls to `get_sidebar` from `index.php` so you have sidebars in different places?

Comment: Yes bcos If I want to show 2 diff sidebars one on footer and other on any other location i.e. header OR both sidebars at footer on single page,  then how would i do that?

Comment: Right. This means you need to pass a piece of information from `index.php` (the place of the call) to `sidebar.php`. This is a tricky issue with mulitple solutions. You can read more about it here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228223/check-if-partial-file-is-called-from-within-header-php-or-footer-php?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple sidebar using vc or wordpress editor by https://codecanyon.net/item/custom-sidebar-visual-editor-wordpress-plugin/17329853

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I wanted to do it by myself. I mean without help of a plugin. But your answer might be helpful for future viewers :)