# Check if I am in the Admin Panel (wp-admin)?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, wp-admin

I want to have my plugin check if the user is anywhere in the **Admin Panel** (`wp-admin`) before executing a script. This would include:

```
/wp-admin/
/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page
/wp-admin/themes.php
etc.
```

Similar to using the using the `global $pagenow`:

```
global $pagenow;
if ( $pagenow == 'upload.php' ) {
    # do something if in the Media page
}
```

From doing some research, it looks like the [`get_current_screen()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) function is something I need, but this is what I've come up which doesn't work:

```
global $my_admin_page;
$screen = get_current_screen();
if ( $screen->id = $my_admin_page ) {
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: This question might help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106895/what-is-the-condition-to-check-if-we-are-in-admin-or-frontend

Comment: You're looking for [`is_admin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/). But beware it also includes `admin-ajax.php` unless you want that file included. For your page you might just check `$_GET['page']` (`options-general.php?page=?`, `admin.php?page=?` ..)

Comment: @czerspalace and @SamuelElh both of you referring to the `is_admin()` helped. Thanks. Do either one of you want to post the answer for the credit and to quickly close this question? Otherwise I'll do it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [is_admin](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) function. By definition, it checks "Whether the current request is for an administrative interface page."

You might also want to verify you are not doing an AJAX call by doing

```
if ( ! is_admin() && ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || ! DOING_AJAX ) ) {
    # code here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What's the reasoning to also check `!DOING_AJAX`? Is that to cover additional pages in the `/wp-admin`?

Comment: As  mentioned by @Samuel Elh, `is_admin` also is true when calling admin-ajax.php, which is used when making AJAX calls from both front-end and back-end. This way it won't return true for AJAX calls